# Using android sdk, is there a way to display photo captured between certain time frame

Tags: android

Using android sdk is it possible to select only those photos based on the date and time the picture was selected.

Comment: This is very vague. What did you try? What exactly do you want to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do the following

1. Get the images data from [data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20185523/list-out-all-images-from-sd-card)
2. In [MediaStore.MediaColumns](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.MediaColumns.html) you will get DATE_ADDED column where you can apply your condition for photos within a time frame.
3. In DATA column u will get the image path and with this you can display the images

Refer this for getting the images [data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20185523/list-out-all-images-from-sd-card)

4. Loading image from sdcard on image view. Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6725718/android-display-image-from-sd-card)