# how to get path of song file from default music player when click song list?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I want to get path of songs which is showing in music player. My problem is that when i click song it is playing. i do not want to play in music player. it should be finish.

I want to get path of song when i click the row of list.

Thank You

Comment: what you actually want?? play the song or get the only selected path of the song from the sd card

Comment: @RavindraKushwaha hello bro, i am doing that, i call intent to open media  player which is given by android and when it is open then click the row of list then i want to fetch path of song file but i dont want to play this song.

Comment: @RavindraKushwaha only selected path of the song. and finish music player.

Comment: Means you want to get only the path of the mp3 songs???

Comment: @RavindraKushwaha yes

Comment: @RavindraKushwaha Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.INTENT_ACTION_MUSIC_PLAYER);
                startActivity(intent);

Comment: @RavindraKushwaha with this intent i am able to open music player.

Comment: Use these link for it  http://stackoverflow.com/a/20185851/3946958   and In the link 's answer they make check of PNG file...You just write there .mp3 OR .MP3 ...And you will able to find the path of the sd card images

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103701/discussion-between-mayank-sugandhi-and-ravindra-kushwaha).