# Scanning internal storage in android for all images

Tags: android, filesystems

I am trying to scan internal storage for all the available images, but getting 0 results, where as, i store one image just before doing the scan, that image is "wallpaper.jpg".

Thanks in advance for any help.

```
boolean fileFlag= fileExistance("/wallpaper.jpg");
    System.out.println(fileFlag); // this returns "true"

    initMediaContentLevels(TAG, Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, CoreConstants.DATATYPE_PHOTO, listener);



protected void initMediaContentLevels(final String tag, final Uri mediaUri, final int dataType, final DataManagerListener listener) {
    LOG.i(TAG, "initMediaContentLevels("+tag+","+mediaUri+","+dataType+") mClassItemsTotal="+mClassItemsTotal);
    //TODO if the data card is not mounted or missing then this returns 0 .. should test that sd card is available when app starts
    String[] projection = {MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA};
    Cursor mediaExtCur = sContext.getContentResolver().query(
                                                mediaUri,
                                                projection,
                                                null,
                                                null, 
                                                null);





    LOG.d(TAG, "initMediaContentLevels("+tag+","+mediaUri+","+dataType+") mediaExtCur="+mediaExtCur);
    if (mediaExtCur!=null) {
        int numItems = mediaExtCur.getCount();     //allows for chaining of class for one upload group (row of UI)
        LOG.d(TAG, "initMediaContentLevels("+tag+") numItems="+numItems);
        try {
            if (numItems > 0) {
                while (mediaExtCur.moveToNext()) {
                    String filepath = getString(mediaExtCur, MediaColumns.DATA);
                    File f = new File(filepath);
                    if (!f.exists() || !f.canRead()) {
                        LOG.e(TAG, "initMediaContentLevels("+tag+") file "+f.getAbsolutePath()+" "+(f.exists()?"is not readable":"does not exist"));
                        continue;
                    }
                    long fileSize = f.length();
                    if (exceedsFileSizeLimit(fileSize)) {
                        LOG.e(TAG, "initMediaContentLevels("+tag+") file is too large to announce "+filepath+": "+fileSize);
                        //files larger than the max are not counted
                        continue;
                    }
                    mBytesTotal += fileSize;   //db sizes are unreliable
                    mClassItemsTotal++;
                }
                LOG.d(TAG, "initMediaContentLevels("+tag+") mBytesTotal="+mBytesTotal+", mClassItemsTotal="+mClassItemsTotal);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)  {
            LOG.e(TAG,"problem getting media count "+e.toString());
        }
        finally {
            if (!mediaExtCur.isClosed()) {
                mediaExtCur.close();
            }
        }
    }

    LOG.d(TAG, "initMediaContentLevels("+tag+") listener="+listener);
    listener.initialiseClassCount(dataType, mClassItemsTotal, mBytesTotal);
    LOG.d(TAG, "initMediaContentLevels("+tag+") done");
}
```

Comment: `trying to scan internal storage ` No. You are querying the MediaStore for something.

Comment: How do i scan the internal storage?

Comment: Nowhere in your code we can see something that concerns images.

Comment: Hey try **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20185523/list-out-all-images-from-sd-card**. Hope it will help you out.

Comment: Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI

Comment: Any help on this ??