# How to get images from Sd card and put into array list

Tags: android, android-bitmap

I want to make slide show and I will get images from Sd card. I wanna use several images, how can I put my images into arrylist ? below is that my code for one image.

```
ImageView imageview = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/sdcard2/image/index1.png");
    imageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Comment: using content uri you can achieve this thing.

Comment: How can I use uri , could u help me about that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [List out all images from SD card.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20185523/list-out-all-images-from-sd-card)

Comment: u mean my image name ( index1.png , index2.png .. until index5.png )

Answer (score 0):

below is the answer you can use it for fetching images for sd card using content uri,try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20185523/list-out-all-images-from-sd-card),this will surely work for you,assuming you have the knowledge regarding content uri.

Comment: Im new to Android , I dont know very much

Comment: have you visit the answer?

Comment: shoul I write my file name instead of PHOTO;_ALBUM

Comment: i think that is dir from  where you are fetching the data.