# Read Downloaded images from the "Downloads" folder from the Shared Storage in Android Emulator using MediaStore. Cursor object returns with size 0

Tags: java, android, mediastore, android-external-storage

I am looking to read a set of image files from the `sdcard/download` directory. I am getting `content://media/external_primary/downloads` as the URI string when calling

```
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            collection = MediaStore.Downloads.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL_PRIMARY);
        } else {
            collection = MediaStore.Downloads.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        }
```

I am using the `Cursor` interface to iterate through the directory but for some reason, my cursor is returning with a `size` of `0`. I do not know what I am doing wrong to make this happen but below is the code that I have so far. Looking for some direction.

```
  Uri collection;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            collection = MediaStore.Downloads.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL_PRIMARY);
        } else {
            collection = MediaStore.Downloads.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

        }

            String[] projection = {
                    MediaStore.MediaColumns._ID,
                    MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE
            };

            try {
                Cursor cursor = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(collection, projection, null, null, null);

                // Cache column indices.
                int idColumn = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Downloads._ID);

                int nameColumn = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Downloads.TITLE);

                while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

                    // Get values of columns for a given video.
                    long id = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Downloads._ID));
                    String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Downloads.DISPLAY_NAME));

                    Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(MediaStore.Downloads.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, id);

                    ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
                    imageView.setImageURI(contentUri);

                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Snippet to the directory structure

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELkQw.png

Comment: check this one
https://stackoverflow.com/a/20185851/6075059

Comment: Android version of used device?

Comment: API 31 @blackapps

Comment: If they are no files created by your app you will normally not see them on an Android 11+ device.